# LIKE works partially to search char from data base in SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, c#-2.0

`tbSearch.Text` is a text box value on the page and `searchText` is string data type value received at drop down list box selected index change event.

I receive both value perfectly from the text box and drop down list box, but I am unable to search data from the table.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE showData
@search varchar(MAX)=NULL,
@status varchar(50)=NULL
AS
BEGIN   
    if @status = 'LANDLINE' and @search != ''
    BEGIN
       SELECT c.contid    AS ID, 
          c.contname  AS Person, 
          b.bustype   AS Business, 
          c.comp      AS Company, 
       c.email1    AS Email, 
       c.email2    AS Email, 
       c.website   AS Website, 
       c.landline1 AS Landline, 
       c.landline2 AS Landline, 
       c.mobile1   AS Mobile, 
       c.mobile2   AS Mobile, 
       c.street    AS Street, 
       c.city      AS City, 
       c.zip       AS ZipCode, 
       c.state     AS State, 
       c.country   AS Country 
    FROM   contactinfo c 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN businessinfo b 
                    ON c.bustype = b.bustype 
    WHERE  c.landline1 LIKE '%' + @search + '%' 
        OR c.landline2 LIKE '%' + @search + '%' 
   END
END
RETURN
```

Calling C# code:

```
protected void btSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("showData", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", tbSearch.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", searchText);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds.Clear();
    da.Fill(ds);  

GridViewSearch.Visible = true;
    GridViewSearch.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridViewSearch.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Does it run without exceptions, but with no rows being found? I'm asking because I don't see where the 'searchText' value is coming from...

Answer (score 0):

Replace NULL with ' '

```
@Search varchar(MAX)=''
@status varchar(50)=''
```